# Data Validation from external database

Tags: python, database, validation

What would be the best way to validate data in a external database using python. Does anyone have any examples? Lets say that I wanted to check whether or not product categories were correct in a program called SAP what would be the best approach to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get data from an database I would recommend to use [sqlalchemy](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/). They provide a huge toolset to get some insights of your database.
Check out the [SAP Hana connector](https://github.com/SAP/sqlalchemy-hana) to establish a connection.